S3 event notification is not being updated when redeployed with a new filter configuration; instead, a new notification is being created
We have an application utilizing serverless technology with AWS Lambda and manage our infrastructure using AWS CDK. However, we are working with an existing S3 bucket that is not managed by AWS CDK. Our goal is to add an S3 event notification to this bucket, which will trigger a Lambda function when an object is added. Below is the code we are using to add the S3 event notification:
lambda.addEventSource(S3EventSourceV2.Builder.create(bucket)
    .events(List.of(EventType.OBJECT_CREATED_PUT))
    .filters(List.of(NotificationKeyFilter.builder().prefix("images/")
        .suffix(".jpg")
        .build())
);

Up to this point, everything works as expected. However, when we update the suffix to '.png' and redeploy the solution, all the existing notifications attached to the S3 bucket are altered. The S3 event names change from the Lambda ARN to a random value (e.g., 'MDNhYjk0Y2QtBjg0MC00YmIxLTgyNjMtNDA3Yjc4NDk2Mgdp'), making the existing S3 event objects unmodifiable. While the filter is still present, the Lambda function is no longer able to track it. Additionally, the previous notification from my Lambda function is not updated; instead, a new filter with the ARN is added, and the old event name is replaced with the random value.
To address this, we also attempted a bucket-centric approach, as shown below:
s3Bucket.addEventNotification(
    software.amazon.awscdk.services.s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED,
    new LambdaDestination(lambdaFunction),
    software.amazon.awscdk.services.s3.notifications.NotificationKeyFilter.builder()
        .prefix("images/")
        .suffix(".jpg")
        .build()
);

However, the issue persists. We also checked the cnfBucket notification configuration, but it ends up removing all the existing notification events.
Could you please advise on how we can update only the notification for our Lambda function without removing the other existing notifications or adding a new one?

Doubtless you have seen this question but I wanted to add it because it's closely related.
